# how to send parameters to form class when creating instance in views in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Hai i have following code in views

```
def fillappraisaltestform(request,temp_id):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = FillAppraisalTestForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            comments = form.cleaned_data['Comments']
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = FillAppraisalTestForm(temp_id) # An unbound form


    return render(request, 'schdeules/fill_appraisal_test_form.html', {'form': form,})
```

and my forms code is

```
class QuestionIteratedFieldsMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs['base_fields'] = get_declared_fields(bases, attrs)

        for question in tbtrnappraisalquestion.objects.filter(intTemplateID_id=temp_id).order_by('intPartID','intSectionID','intOrder'):
            attrs['base_fields']['textbox_question%s' % question.intQuesID] = forms.CharField(label = question.txtQuestion,required=True)

        new_class = super(QuestionIteratedFieldsMetaclass,
                 cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
    if 'media' not in attrs:
        new_class.media = media_property(new_class)
    return new_class   

class FillAppraisalTestForm(six.with_metaclass(QuestionIteratedFieldsMetaclass, forms.BaseForm),temp_id):
    pass
```

my question is how to send template id from views to form and then to QuestionIteratedFieldsMetaclass.so that i can get the questions of that particular template id?

Comment: I'm working on it. But first of all please remove `temp_id` from `QuestionIteratedFieldsMetaclass(type,temp_id)` it's a class you pass other classes there for inheritance not arguments.

Comment: Nope. Sorry can't handle it.

Comment: is there any other way to get that requirement.

Comment: k i am keeping template id in session.so how to access that session templated id in forms.py.like this request.session['current_temp_id'].but it is saying request is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why you are using a metaclass here, it's complete overkill. You could achieve the same effect simply by using a standard modelform and overriding `__init__`.

```
class FillAppraisalTestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        temp_id = kwargs.pop('temp_id', None)
        super(FillAppraisalTestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for question in tbtrnappraisalquestion.objects.filter(intTemplateID_id=temp_id).order_by('intPartID','intSectionID','intOrder'):
            self.fields['textbox_question%s' % question.intQuesID] = forms.CharField(label=question.txtQuestion, required=True)
```

Now you can instantiate the form with `FillAppraisalTestForm(request.POST, temp_id=temp_id)`.

Comment: instead of using modelform i am using forms.form.and i implemented same code in it it is working fine.Thank you.i am posting my edited content